# Span Wrapping Issue

Tags: css, css-float

I am not sure how to force the span on the right hand side from encroaching into the span on the left hand side. My intention is to keep the value (black text) in a separate column and not allow it to enter into the caption column.

Please note I am using the term column loosely here.

I have created a fiddle here to demonstrate my issue ...
http://jsfiddle.net/yrFNq/

```
<span id="Label8" class="caption1">Discount Type</span>
<span id="Label9" style="border: dashed 1px aqua; width:256px;">
 Full time tertiary students, seniors, pensioners &amp; people on unemployment benefits
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
display: table-cell;
```

style for spans.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/maximkou/yrFNq/3/

Answer (score 2):

Just add `height: 100%;` to your `caption1` class, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yrFNq/2/).